# PHP&HTML: как выводить разные сообщения при неудачной отравке формы

Tags: php, html

Такая задача: проверяя введённые данные на стороне сервера, прервать выполнение скрипта отправки и вывести соответствующее сообщение об ошибке (такое как "введённое имя слишком короткое", "неправильно введён номер телефона" и т. д.).

Чего я не понимаю - как вернуть какое-либо значение при завершении выполнения скрипта, чтобы его можно было перехварить в php-файле с формой ввода. Я себе это представляю как-то так:

```
<!-- action.php - файл проверки данных и отправки сообщения -->
<form id="FeedbackFrom" name="FeedbackFrom" method="post" action="request.php">

    <input type="text" id="name"  name="name">  

    <?php
        if ($_GET['mail'] == 0 && $errorCode == "TooShortName") {
            echo "<p class=\"error\"> Введённое имя слишком короткое </p>";
        }
        else if ($_GET['mail'] == 0 && $errorCode == "TooShortName") {
            echo "<p class=\"error\"> Введённое имя слишком длинное </p>";
        }
    ?>

    <input type="email" id="email"  name="email">

    <?php
        if ($_GET['mail'] == 0 && $errorCode == "InvalidMail") {
            echo "<p class=\"error\"> Адрес электронной почты ведён неправильно </p>";
        }
    ?>

    <input type ="submit" id="Submitt"/>

</form>
```

- Есть `exit`, но он ничего не возвращает. Код ошибки там ловится какими-то извращенскими способами; непонятно, как поймать его в блоке `if`.
- Есть исключения и конструкция `try-catch`. Но во-первых, нужно создавать отдельный класс для каждой ошибки, во-вторых как это "поймать" при аварийном завершении `request.php`?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$error = array();

$name = '';
$email = '';

// Если пришло значение
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
  $name = $_POST['name']; 
  // Если там пусто
  if(!$_POST['name']){
     $error['name'] = 'Пустое имя';
  }
}
// Если пришло значение
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  // Если там пусто
  if(!$_POST['email']){
     $error['email'] = 'Пустой email';
  }
}


if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && (!$error)){
  mail($_POST['email'], 'Вы правильно заполнили форму', 'Ok' );
  die(); // Тут должен быть редирект на другую страницу
}


?>


<form id="FeedbackFrom" name="FeedbackFrom" method="post" action="request.php">

<input type="text" id="name"  name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">  
<?php
if(isset($error['name'])){
  echo '<p class="error">' . $error['name'] . '</p>'; 
}
?>

<input type="email" id="email"  name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
<?php
if(isset($error['email'])){
  echo '<p class="error">' . $error['email'] . '</p>'; 
}
?>
    <input type ="submit" id="Submitt"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если вкратце - как вариант в этих блоках ставить метку что есть ошибки заполнения

```
if ($_GET['mail'] == 0 && $errorCode == "TooShortName") {
    $form_invalid = true;
    echo "<p class=\"error\"> Введённое имя слишком короткое </p>";
}
```

И в конце файла

```
if ( empty($form_invalid) ) {
    // http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_email.asp
    $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);  
    mail($_POST['email'], 'Вы правильно заполнили форму', 'Ok' );
    header('Location: action.php?mail_send=true');
    die(); // Тут должен быть редирект на другую страницу, иначе при каждой перезагрузке станицы будет отправляться письмо
}
```

Но как по мне лучше использовать AJAX, это гораздо удобнее.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Никогда не использовал AJAX; он связан с JavaScript? Я вообще пишу PHP код-проверки формы для случая, когда JavaScript отключен, а так у меня JS всё уже проверяет.

Comment: Если JavaScript отключен, тогда и AJAX не будет работать.

@Я вообще пишу PHP код-проверки формы для случая, когда JavaScript отключен@
JS валидация не исключает PHP валидацию, даже при включенном JS пользователь может отправить что-то не так.

Comment: Всё верно, именно поэтому и на один AJAX полагаться тоже нельзя.